Find periodic task's next execution time in Celery Beat
I am creating PeriodicTasks for opening user an access to the next lesson using this code:
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
            interval=enrolment.course.interval,
            name=f"enrolment_id: {enrolment.id}",
            task="courses.tasks.next_program",
            args=json.dumps([enrolment.id]),
        )
enrolment.task = task
enrolment.save()

How to get datetime next task will be ran?

what value is in enrolment.course.interval ? Maybe it needs only datatime.datetime.now() + enrolment.course.interval. Or maybe it needs to convert interval to datetime.timedelta(...) and later use + like .now() + timedelta(...). And if you want next values then .now()+2*timedelta , .now()+3*timedelta , etc.

BTW: if you want to check it later then you have to get datatime.datetime.now() (as start_time) and interval (as timedelta) when you create task and keep this value to use it later to calculate the nearest next task. You could run loop next_task = start_time while next_task < datatime.datetime.now(): next_task += timedelta

enrolment.course.interval is a models.ForeignKey(IntervalSchedule, ...)
And for now  I use this code:
        task = self.next_program_task
        if not task:
            return 0
        last_run_at = task.last_run_at or task.start_time or self.datetime_created
        return timezone.now() + task.schedule.remaining_estimate(last_run_at)



if this code resolved your problem then you could put it as answer - and you can mark you answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote your answer.

I used celery's built-in schedule.remaining_estimate:
def datetime_next_lesson(self):
    task = self.task
    if not task: # just in case
        return 0
    # if task hasn't been run yet, last_run_at will be null, use datetime_created in this case
    last_run_at = task.last_run_at or task.start_time or self.datetime_created
    return timezone.now() + task.schedule.remaining_estimate(last_run_at)

